# Inserir conteúdo dentro da template WebComponents

Tags: javascript, web-component

estou fazendo um WebComponent e me deparei com uma situação:
O conteúdo não fica dentro da template do componente.

Se inspecionar abaixo, o "Teste de alerta" é posicionado abaixo do template invés de dentro. Pesquisei sobre slots mas não entendi como utilizá-lo.

Peço ajuda pra esclarecer a utilização e se estou fazendo algo errado. Grato!

```js
class Alert extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this._priority = null;
        this._typeClass = '';
        this._iconClass = '';
        this._alertTypeName = '';
        this._alertPriority = null;
    }

    get type() {
        return this.getAttribute('type');
    }

    get priority() {
        return this.getAttribute('priority');
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['type', 'priority'];
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(type, oldVal, newVal) {
        console.log(this.shadow)
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        switch (this.type) {

            case "success":
                this._alertTypeName = "Sucesso";
                this._typeClass = "alert-success";
                this._iconClass = "glyphicon-ok";
                this._alertPriority = this.priority;
                break;

            case "info":
                this._alertTypeName = "Informação";
                this._typeClass = "alert-info";
                this._iconClass = "glyphicon-info-sign";
                this._alertPriority = this.priority;
                break;

            case "warning":
                this._alertTypeName = "Aviso";
                this._typeClass = "alert-warning";
                this._iconClass = "glyphicon-warning-sign";
                this._alertPriority = this.priority;
                break;

            case "error":
                this._alertTypeName = "Erro";
                this._typeClass = "alert-danger";
                this._iconClass = "glyphicon-exclamation-sign";
                this._alertPriority = "alert";
                break;
        }

        var template = `
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible fade show" role>
            <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
    `;

        this.shadow.innerHTML = template;
        var alertElement = this.shadow.querySelector('.alert');

        alertElement.setAttribute("role", this._alertPriority);
        alertElement.children[0].setAttribute("aria-label", this._alertTypeName);
        alertElement.classList.add(this._typeClass);
        alertElement.children[0].classList.add(this._iconClass);
    }

}

window.customElements.define('meu-alert', Alert);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<meu-alert type="success" priority="alert">
Teste de alerta
</meu-alert>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas de adicionar um conteúdo a um elemento customizado é utilizar o elemento [`<slot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot)

Este elemento faz parte da tecnologia de *Web Components* do *JavaScript*. Com ele é possível substituir ou adicionar um conteúdo do `<template>`.

Há duas formas de utilizar o elemento supramencionado:

- Informar o atributo nome
- Deixar vazio o atributo nome

Ao definir um nome para o `<slot>`, podemos ter múltiplos desses para criar uma estrutura. Por exemplo:

```
<!-- Template -->
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="header"></slot>
    <slot name="content"></slot>
    <slot name="footer"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- No código -->
<custom-element>
  <header slot="header">...</header>
  <section slot="content">...</section>
  <footer slot="footer">...</footer>
</custom-element>
```

Deixando o atributo `name` vazio, estaremos definindo que o esse `slot` será o padrão. Ou seja, todo conteúdo (caso haja) dentro do elemento customizado irá sobrescrever o conteúdo padrão do `slot`.

**Exemplo prático:**

```js
class Alert extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        const newTemplate = document.createElement('template')
        newTemplate.innerHTML = `
          <style>@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')</style>

          <div class="alert alert-${this.type} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        `
        
        const nodes = newTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)
        
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(nodes);
    }

    get type () {
        let type = this.getAttribute('type');
        
        return !!['success', 'danger'].includes(type)
          ? type
          : 'primary'
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['type'];
    }
}

window.customElements.define('meu-alert', Alert);
```

```html
<meu-alert type="danger">
  Teste de alerta
</meu-alert>
```

**Alternativa**

A segunda alternativa e mais fácil, é capturar o conteúdo do elemento personalizado através da propriedade `this.innerHTML`. Com isso, o *JavaScript* retornar-te-á o que fora informado no conteúdo do elemento customizado.

```js
class Alert extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        
        let slotFictitious = this.innerHTML

        const newTemplate = document.createElement('template')
        newTemplate.innerHTML = `
          <div class="alert alert-${this.type} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            ${slotFictitious}
          </div>
        `
        
        const nodes = newTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)
        
        this.innerHTML = nodes.firstElementChild.outerHTML
    }

    get type () {
        let type = this.getAttribute('type');
        
        return !!['success', 'error'].includes(type)
          ? type
          : 'primary'
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['type'];
    }
}

window.customElements.define('meu-alert', Alert);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meu-alert type="success">
  Teste de alerta 2
</meu-alert>
```

Comment: Cara maravilho, esclareceu muito pra mim! Obrigado!